# Create NSWindow in Objective-C from pointer?

Tags: java, objective-c, accessibility, lwjgl

Let's say I am creating a window with LWJGL 3 which allows me to get a pointer to the underlying NSWindow via *GLFWNativeCocoa#glfwGetCocoaWindow(long: window)*, i.e.:

```
140616305790880
```

With this pointer, if I perform a native call and pass it to an objective-C function, is it possible to instantiate an NSWindow or get a reference to it so I can manipulate the window from a lower level?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Doing a quick search for `glfwGetCocoaWindow` in the lwjgl source code gives the following example as a result: `modules/samples/src/test/java/org/lwjgl/demo/glfw/Gears.java`. In the example, they don't do a straight up Objective-C call to the `cocoaWindow` handler, but instead do a msgSend to a selector on that window handle instead. Here's the code:

```
if ( Platform.get() == Platform.MACOSX ) {
    long cocoaWindow = glfwGetCocoaWindow(window);

    long objc_msgSend = ObjCRuntime.getLibrary().getFunctionAddress("objc_msgSend");
    long contentView = invokePPP(objc_msgSend, cocoaWindow, sel_getUid("contentView"));

    invokePPV(objc_msgSend, contentView, sel_getUid("setWantsBestResolutionOpenGLSurface:"), false);

    boolean bool = invokePPZ(objc_msgSend, contentView, sel_getUid("wantsBestResolutionOpenGLSurface"));
        System.out.println("wantsBestResolutionOpenGLSurface = " + bool);
}
```

It would be worth trying a different selector than the `"contentView"`, as in the code above.